# Why is JqGrid losing the rightmost column border when Grouping is active?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a grid without too much customization that renders fine with `grouping: false`

If I turn on grouping, the border disappears, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

The CSS classes for one of the cells regarding border are `ui-jqgrid` and `TR.ui-row-ltr TD` which have the border set to `1px solid`, but it doesn't actually render. If I turn off the border attribute, it removes it from the grouping row and all other rows in the grid.

Any thoughts on how to get this border to draw? Thanks!

**Grid definition by request:**

```
{
        colNames: ["ItemId", "DetailId", "UPC", "Ship Date", "Vendor", "VendorDisplay", "Item", "UPC", "Description", "Pack", "Ret", "Exp", "Inv", "Memo", "Distro", "Requst", "Reason"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "ItemId", index: "ItemId", width: 1, hidden: true },
            { name: "DetailId", index: "DetailId", width: 1, hidden: true, editable: true },
            { name: "UPC", index: "UPC", width: 1, hidden: true },
            { name: "ShipDateDisplay", index: "ShipDateDisplay", width: 65, stype: "text", searchoptions: { dataInit: GridModels.Formatters.DatePicker, attr: { title: "Select Date"}} },                
            { name: "Vendor", index: "Vendor", width: 0, hidden: true, stype: "select", searchoptions: { searchhidden: true, value: "0:Vendor1;1:Vendor2"} },                
            { name: "VendorDisplay", index: "VendorDisplay", hidden: true },
            { name: "VendorItem", index: "VendorItem", width: 40, align: "Right" },
            { name: "UPC_DISPLAY", index: "UPC_DISPLAY", width: 70, align: "Right" },
            { name: "ItemDescription", index: "ItemDescription", width: 200 },
            { name: "CasePack", index: "CasePack", width: 35, align: "Right" },
            { name: "Retail", index: "Retail", width: 50, align: "Right", search: false, formatter: Store.Cuts.Common.RetailLoader },               
            { name: "InvQty", index: "InvQty", width: 50, align: "Right", search: false, formatter: Store.Cuts.Common.InventoryLoader },
            { name: "Memo", index: "Memo", width: 50 },
            { name: "Qty", index: "Qty", width: 30, align: "Right", search: false },
            { name: "StoreQty", index: "StoreQty", width: 35, align: "Right", search: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true, integer: true, minValue: 0} },
            { name: "StoreReason", index: "StoreReason", width: 130, align: "Right", search: false, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: reasons} }
        ],
        editurl: editurl,
        url: gridurl,
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['VendorDisplay'],
            groupColumnShow: false,
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupDataSorted: true
        },
        pager: pager,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20            
    };

$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
            datatype: 'json',
            height: "100%",
            loadui: 'none',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "Rows",
                page: "Page",
                total: "Total",
                records: "Records",
                repeatitems: false,
                userdata: "UserData",
                id: "Id",
                subgrid:
                {
                    root: "Rows",
                    repeatitems: false
                }
            },
            mtype: 'GET',
            autowidth: true,
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            viewrecords: true,              
            beforeRequest: function () {
                $("#load_grid").html('<h4 style="display: inline; position: relative; top: -10px; font-weight: bold">Loading...</h4>' + $(".loader").html());
                Common.Grid.DisableControls();
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                if (!loadonce)
                    loadonce = true;

                if ($("#grid").getGridParam("reccount") === 0)
                    Common.Grid.DisplayStatus("No records found...");
                else
                    Common.Grid.HideStatus();

                if (loadCompleteEx)
                    loadCompleteEx();
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                if (!loadonce) {
                    Common.Grid.LoadNavBar($(this));

                    // Align check all checkbox better
                    $("th[id=grid_cb]")
                        .css("text-align", "center")
                        .css("position", "relative")
                        .css("left", "1px");
                }

                if (gridCompleteEx)
                    gridCompleteEx();

                Common.Grid.EnableControls();
            }
        });
```

You can use the following JSON string to populate the grid with test data which causes the problem on my end:

```
{"Total":1,"Page":1,"Records":3,"Rows":[{"Id":1,"Description":"","ShipDate":"/Date(-62135578800000)/","ShipDateDisplay":"01/01/0001","Type":null,"IsAvailableToStores":false,"IsReadOnly":false,"IsStoreFinalized":false,"IsHQFinalized":false,"IsDeleted":false,"BuyerId":0,"Buyer":null,"Memo":null,"ItemId":0,"Vendor":"01111","VendorDisplay":"1111 - ","VendorName":null,"VendorItem":null,"UPC_DISPLAY":"00000-01111","UPC":"1111","ItemDescription":"Test","CasePack":0,"RetailAmt":0,"RetailMult":0,"Retail":"$0.00","SaleAmt":0,"SaleMult":0,"ExpressAmt":null,"ExpressMult":null,"InvQty":0,"DetailId":0,"StoreNumber":0,"StoreName":null,"OriginalQty":0,"BuyerQty":0,"Qty":0,"StoreQty":0,"StoreReason":null,"FinalQty":0},{"Id":2,"Description":"","ShipDate":"/Date(-62135578800000)/","ShipDateDisplay":"01/01/0001","Type":null,"IsAvailableToStores":false,"IsReadOnly":false,"IsStoreFinalized":false,"IsHQFinalized":false,"IsDeleted":false,"BuyerId":0,"Buyer":null,"Memo":null,"ItemId":0,"Vendor":"01111","VendorDisplay":"1111 - ","VendorName":null,"VendorItem":null,"UPC_DISPLAY":"00000-01111","UPC":"1111","ItemDescription":"Test","CasePack":0,"RetailAmt":0,"RetailMult":0,"Retail":"$0.00","SaleAmt":0,"SaleMult":0,"ExpressAmt":null,"ExpressMult":null,"InvQty":0,"DetailId":0,"StoreNumber":0,"StoreName":null,"OriginalQty":0,"BuyerQty":0,"Qty":0,"StoreQty":0,"StoreReason":null,"FinalQty":0},{"Id":3,"Description":"","ShipDate":"/Date(-62135578800000)/","ShipDateDisplay":"01/01/0001","Type":null,"IsAvailableToStores":false,"IsReadOnly":false,"IsStoreFinalized":false,"IsHQFinalized":false,"IsDeleted":false,"BuyerId":0,"Buyer":null,"Memo":null,"ItemId":0,"Vendor":"02222","VendorDisplay":"2222 - ","VendorName":null,"VendorItem":null,"UPC_DISPLAY":"00000-01111","UPC":"1111","ItemDescription":"Test","CasePack":0,"RetailAmt":0,"RetailMult":0,"Retail":"$0.00","SaleAmt":0,"SaleMult":0,"ExpressAmt":null,"ExpressMult":null,"InvQty":0,"DetailId":0,"StoreNumber":0,"StoreName":null,"OriginalQty":0,"BuyerQty":0,"Qty":0,"StoreQty":0,"StoreReason":null,"FinalQty":0}],"UserData":null}
```

Comment: Could you include the definition of the grid which can be used to reproduce your problem. The simple [grouping demos](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Grouping1.htm) or other more complex examples like [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon8.htm) have no described problem.

Comment: @Oleg Added the code...let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: The methods `ondblClickRow` and `onSelectRow` seems me not important because you have problems at the grid loading already. What I need are the test data which produce the problem. I see no `datatype` definition. Do you use default `datatype: 'xml'` datatype?

Comment: @Oleg I always forget about my defaults. I added those beneath the original code. Thanks again for your help. The browser I'm using btw is IE8.

Comment: I still have no test data which can be grouped by 'VendorDisplay' and which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry, I am reading things hastily. I have created some test data that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you posted include many undefined functions like custom formatters and so on. After I commented all unknown parts I received [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Grouping2.htm) which has no effects which you described. Probably the problems which you described not exist without the parts of the code which you not posted. If you posted the URL which can be used to see the problem live (of course with unminimized jqGrid code `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) I could take a look inside.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. After a goodnight's sleep and being more apt to troubleshoot this morning, I figured out what was wrong with it. Please see my posted answer. Would you consider this a bug that should be reported on the jqGrid forums?

Comment: @IronicMuffin: You are welcome! Do don't posted the values of `reasons` and don't describes that you have the problem only *after the inline editing are used*. From my point of view it is a bug what you describe in your last post. So I recommend you to prepare a small demo with the long string in the `editoptions.value` and simple usage of the inline editing. The demo you should post to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/) so that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) could fix the bug.

Comment: I think I got excited too soon. Now it is appearing and disappearing as I resize columns. I think I just got lucky on the width parameter. If I drag columns such that the grid needs a horizontal scrollbar, and then resize them back, it may or may not appear. It's very strange.